# Are geodesic preserved by projections in hyperbolic space?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, projection, geodesic

In a the euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^n$ a line $\alpha$ is mapped to a line $\pi(\alpha)$ by an othogonal projection $\pi:\mathbb{E}^n\to P$ to some plane $P$.
Projections in the hyperbolic space shares some properties with $\mathbb{E}$, for example projections to convex geodesic subspaces are contractive. Hence the following question.

Let then $\pi$ be the projection of $\mathbb{H}^n$ to some geodesic plane $P\subset H$: is it true that $\pi$ maps geodesic intervals $\ell$ to geodesic intervals $\pi(\ell)$?

Comment: What is $P$ and what are you projecting hyperbolic geodesics to?

Comment: Thanks! I clarified the question! $P$ is just a plane, but it might be any affine subspace, and analogously I'm projecting hyperbolic gedeosics to hyperbolic planes $H^2\subset H$

Comment: You should also specify that by a geodesic in a hyperbolic space you mean a (possibly open) geodesic interval.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. The following proof works in $\mathbb{H}^3$ and is better understood if drawn while read, but I think it can be generalized to any dimension.

Recall that in the upper half-space model *geodesic planes* are vertical planes (i.e. orthogonal to the boundary) or hemispheres whose center lies on the boundary, while *geodesic intervals* are contained in straight lines orthogonal to the boundary or vertical semicircles (i.e. contained in a vertical plane) whose center lies on the boundary. From now on we will always assume that planes and circles are vertical.

We can assume without loss of generality that $P$ is a vertical plane. To project a point $x\notin P$ to $P$ take the unique circle $C=C(x,P)$ passing through $x$, orthogonal to $P$, and whose center lies in $P$, then the projection $\pi(x)$ is just the intersection $C\cap P$.

If the geodesic segment $\ell$ is contained in a vertical line then the statement is immediate, so suppose that $\ell$ is contained in a unique circle $C_\ell$. Let $S_\ell$ be the unique sphere that contains $C_\ell$ and whose center lies in $P$. Then for any point $x\in\ell$ the circle $C(x,P)$ projecting $x$ to $P$ is given by the intersection of this sphere with a plane orthogonal to $P$ and passing through $x$. This shows that $p(\ell)\subset S_\ell\cap P$ and hence conclude the proof, since it is contained in the circle.